# How To Make AutoCompleteSource.HistoryList Into A Usable String

Tags: c#, autocomplete

All I am simply trying to do is display the `AutoCompleteSource.HistoryList` in a message box. All the following code does is display the words HistoryList.  How can I make it actually show the URLS of the HistoryLIst, in other words I want the contents of the HistoryList to appear in the MessageBox.

```
string s = AutoCompleteSource.HistoryList;
MessageBox.Show(s, "History", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Have a look at the following [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textbox.autocompletesource%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) page that might further your learning. The MessageBox is showing HistoryList bacause that is exactly what you have programmed it to do!

Comment: Well anyone have any solutions.